# Drools Rule Engine - Multiple .drl file for different set of rules for different context

Tags: jboss, drools, rules, rule-engine

I am using spring boot drools. I would like to maintain say 3 different drl files for different context as the rules are different for different context. In this case should I create 3 key KieContainer for each context or is it possible to handle in just on kie container? Note: for each context I have to invoke only the corresponding drl rules

```
@Bean
public KieContainer getKieContainer() {
KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newFileResource("ctxt1.drl")));
kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newFileResource("ctxt2.drl")));
KieBuilder kb = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem);
kb.buildAll();
KieModule kieModule = kb.getKieModule();
KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieModule.getReleaseId());
return kieContainer;
```

}

this is how I invoke rule. Here I would like to invoke context based drl file rules in the session.
How to use KieBase based KieSession?

```
KieSession kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession();
kieSession.insert(RequestPOJO);
kieSession.fireAllRules();
kieSession.dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the limited description, sounds like "different context" can be identified with a Knowledge Base (`KieBase`).

You can create 1 KJAR with the 3 different DRL files, making sure (e.g.: via package) they correspond to 3 different KieBases.

Something ~like:

```xml
<kmodule>
 <kbase name="KBase1" packages="org.acme,org.context1" />
 <kbase name="KBase2" packages="org.acme,org.context2" />
 <kbase name="KBase3" packages="org.acme,org.context3" />
 ...
</kmodule>
```

Then you could create 1 KieContainer, which contains the single KJAR containing the "multiple contexts" (KieBases).

At that point, from the KieContainer, you can create a KieSession with the specific KieBase you want.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have modified the question with sample code. Could you help to provide some idea on that.

Comment: In your modified Q, you are not accounting for the kmodule.xml file, hence you are not able to locate the KieBase for the "context" you want

Comment: is kmodule.xml mandatory? What I am looking for is if I can programmatically create KieBase and add to KieContainer in getKieContainer() bean  mentioned in the question? Note: I do not want to use KJAR also.

Comment: If you need a clean separation of context, I think the best approach would be to have three separate KieModules and instantiate KieContainers and KieSessions as you need out of them.